# What is equivalent of Canvas.Pixels[X,Y] in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, canvas, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

In VCL we can get the color of specific pixel from Canvas or bitmap like this:

```
Canvas.Pixels[X,Y]
```

but we have not such a thing for canvas and bitmap in firemonkey components. how can we read or write a specific point on a canvas in FMX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume that you are working with a bitmap, if you wish to operate on pixel data. In which case you use the [`Map`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TBitmap.Map) method of the `TBitmap` class. More details here:

- http://www.fmxexpress.com/get-direct-pixel-access-to-bitmaps-in-delphi-xe5-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/
- http://members.adug.org.au/2012/10/05/read-write-image-bitmap-pixels-in-delphi-xe3/
- [http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FMX.AlphaColorToPixel_(Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/en/FMX.AlphaColorToPixel_%28Delphi%29)

Comment: Thanks. it takes some time to figure it out. for the others who want quicker answer I suggest define a `bdata:TBitmapData` in var section and then use `Canvas.MakeScreenshot.Map(TMapAccess.maRead,bdata)` and after that `bdata.GetPixel` function can be used.